# Unable to connect apache vysper XMPP server from Android using Smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to connect to apache vysper XMPP server from my android device.
I'm using smack 4.1 library. I'm getting below exception.

Kindly help me to get rid of this error.

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>
> 07-18 06:57:15.853 22415-22713/com.cvs.strogchat W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:591)
>
> 07-18 06:57:15.853 22415-22713/com.cvs.strogchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initReaderAndWriter(XMPPTCPConnection.java:651)
>
> 07-18 06:57:15.853 22415-22713/com.cvs.strogchat W/System.err:     at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.proceedTLSReceived(XMPPTCPConnection.java:751)
>
> 07-18 06:57:15.853 22415-22723/com.cvs.strogchat W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found." with (a)Smack 4.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819441/certpathvalidatorexception-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found-wit)

Answer (score 0):

I Have solved this issue by explicitly creating secure socket with certificate from the server. I have copied certificate in app resources and pass that certificate  to the SecureSocket.